# How to export in Excel with a button in google script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am doing the following code to export the data of a sheet to an excel, but it is not doing it. this is my code:

codigo.gs

function doGet(e) {

```
Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(e));
if(!e.parameter.page){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate();
}

 var template=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter.page)
 template.action=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return template.evaluate();

return HtmlService
.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

}

function getContenidoSS(e){

var bogus = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1K4yYl6mXdIXKUppCprXvj9o8VpU671EA_x-5HOfoZBs'); 
var ssID = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('ejemplo');

Logger.log(ssID);

var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export?format=xlsx";   
var params = {method:"GET", headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ 
                                     ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);

// save to drive
DriveApp.createFile(response);

var nombre_usuario="se paso la data";

return nombre_usuario;

 }
```

index.html

```
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

   <script>
   function mostrar_contenido(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getContenido).getContenidoSS(document.forms[0]);
   }
  function getContenido(reg){
     $( "#codigo_personal" ).val(reg);
  }


 /*----------------codigo esencial para conectar con codigo.GS----------------------*/
  function preventFormSubmit() {
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
  for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();    
    });
   }   
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

  /* $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabla_trabajo').DataTable();
   } );*/

 </script>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
    <base target="_top">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.6/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css"> 

 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: blue;color: white;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px">
       <CENTER><label style="font-size: 30px;font-family: monospace;font-weight: normal;color:white">ACTIVIDADES</label></CENTER>
   </div>
  <div id="login_contenido" style="margin-left:15px;margin-top:5px">

   <form class="form-inline" id="form_login">
      <div class="form-group mb-2">
         <button  title='exportar hoja' class="btn btn-primary" onclick="mostrar_contenido();"><i class='fas fa-cog fa-1x'></i>&nbsp;EXPORTAR HOJA</button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mb-2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo_personal" name="codigo_personal" placeholder="Ingrese su codigo...">
      </div>
     </form>
   </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.6/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.6/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

what I am looking for is that my "ejemplo" sheet is exported, but that it goes where I want to store it, without the need for me to write a specific path for its download. your response is appreciated

I want it to be exported as in this portal, where clicking on the "Descargar Todo" button shows me a popup where I can host the exported excel

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can I ask you about your goal? 1. Can you explain about the detail of `it is not doing it`? 2. Where do you want to download the Spreadsheet as the excel file to?

Comment: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzD6iz1BhKq0nezG83_X1hwmLAv442JIWApUWcybvmHDj2ZPIHT/exec

Comment: I passed you the link, clicking the button does not allow me to export the name sheet "ejemplo". and also when exporting I want to choose where I would like to save the exported

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tested your Web Apps just now. But it seems that an error occurs at `getContenidoSS`. Can you confirm it again? And I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `when exporting I want to choose where I would like to save the exported`. In your script, it seems that the file is created to the root folder in your Google Drive. Can I ask you about the goal you expect?

Comment: Where is that you want to choose to be exported? Do you mean by that to be able to choose the path inside the webapp?
Please explain with more detail what is that you mean by not working? Is not storing the file right now? Wrong folder? It is giving you an error? Which error?

Comment: add some photos to my question

Comment: at this moment I don't know where the file I'm exporting is being hosted

Comment: that's why I'm requesting that a pop-up appear so I can choose where I want to host it